# Why does adding negative integers in haskell function not work?

Tags: haskell

So I understand that this is one way to do an exponential function using tail recursion while "counting down":

```
exponentialDown :: Int -> Int -> Int
exponentialDown x y = h_exp x y 1

h_exp :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
h_exp x 0 ans = ans
h_exp x y ans = h_exp x (y-1) (ans*x)
```

but if I want to implement it counting up (from negative y to 0), im not too sure why it will run forever and fail? Would appreciate if someone could explain to me why that happens and possibly how to get around it. This was what I have tried:

```
exponentialDown :: Int -> Int -> Int
exponentialDown x y = h_exp x y 1

h_exp :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
h_exp x 0 ans = ans
h_exp x y ans = h_exp x (1-y) (ans*x)
```

I have tried variations of this but got nowhere...

Comment: please add specific concrete [mcve] so we can something specific to address and help you with.

Comment: Write down a sequence `y_{n+1}=1-y_n` starting with some number `y_0`, what do you get?

Comment: also note that `x^-(n+1) = x^(-n - 1) = x^(-n + (-1)) = x^(-n) / x` so your accumulator for the recursive case should be `h_exp x (y-1) (ans / y)` instead. (2 ^ (-2) = 1/4)

Comment: For negative `y`  `x ^ y` is `Float` in genral case, not `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, counting up from a negative number `y` is done with `y+1` in the recursive call, using the guard for `y >= 0` to stop the recursion. `y == 0` is what you actually need, but `>=` is used to make it catch the unwanted case of positive `y`s.

Or you could have the separate `y == 0`  and `y > 0` guarded cases in your function definition, and report an error in the latter case if that's what you prefer.